# npm install cannot find package.json from dependencies of each dependency

Tags: json, npm, vagrant, npm-install, homestead

Recently, I found myself unable to install with npm my js packages.

I tried to do every basic command that generally unlock thoses kind of weird bug but here it doesn't change a thing.

I did the following, multiple times :

- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- re clone my project `git clone <my-project>`
- `reinstall vagrant box laravel/homestead` (fresh npm + nodejs)
- Installed n and tried different versions of nodejs/npm

I run the npm command inside the virtual machine Homestead which runs :

- Homestead 9.4.0
- Ubuntu 18.04
- npm 6.14.4
- node.js v12.16.1

My package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
        "leaflet": "^1.5.1",
        "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.3",
        "leaflet-polylinedecorator": "^1.6.0",
        "leaflet.control.layers.tree": "^0.1.1",
        "vue-search-select": "^2.6.2",
        "vuex": "^3.1.3"
    }
}
```

And I get the following error which is changing time to time from different package and if I install them manually the same error appears with another package. Always trying to find the package.json from a sub-dependecies in its node_modules. Which is really weird.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/project$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"12.16.1","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.1 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.aproba.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: balanced-match@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/balanced-match):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/balanced-match' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.balanced-match.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.1.4 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.chownr.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/code-point-at):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/code-point-at' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.code-point-at.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: concat-map@0.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/concat-map):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/concat-map' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.concat-map.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: console-control-strings@1.1.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/console-control-strings):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/console-control-strings' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.console-control-strings.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-util-is@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/core-util-is):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/core-util-is' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.core-util-is.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.6.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/deep-extend):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/deep-extend' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.deep-extend.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/delegates):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/delegates' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.delegates.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.detect-libc.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs.realpath@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/fs.realpath):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/fs.realpath' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.fs.realpath.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/has-unicode):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/has-unicode' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.has-unicode.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: inherits@2.0.4 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/inherits):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/inherits' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.inherits.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ini.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: isarray@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/isarray):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/isarray' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.isarray.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.5 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ms@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ms):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ms' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ms.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.npm-normalize-package-bin.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/number-is-nan):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/number-is-nan' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.number-is-nan.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: object-assign@4.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/object-assign):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/object-assign' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.object-assign.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-homedir@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-homedir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-homedir' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.os-homedir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-tmpdir@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-tmpdir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-tmpdir' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.os-tmpdir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: path-is-absolute@1.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/path-is-absolute):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/path-is-absolute' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.path-is-absolute.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: process-nextick-args@2.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/process-nextick-args):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/process-nextick-args' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.process-nextick-args.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safe-buffer@5.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safe-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safe-buffer' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.safe-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safer-buffer@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safer-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safer-buffer' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.safer-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sax@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/sax):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/sax' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.sax.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.7.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.semver.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/set-blocking):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/set-blocking' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.set-blocking.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/signal-exit):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/signal-exit' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.signal-exit.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-json-comments@2.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/strip-json-comments):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/strip-json-comments' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.strip-json-comments.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/util-deprecate):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/util-deprecate' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.util-deprecate.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/wrappy):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/wrappy' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.wrappy.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/yallist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/yallist' -> '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.yallist.DELETE'

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/project/node_modules/archive-type/node_modules/file-type/package.json.739239272
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/project/node_modules/archive-type/node_modules/file-type/package.json.739239272'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-04-15T16_25_14_245Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try `npm update`?

Comment: I tried `npm update` but since my `npm install` cannot finish it returns nothing. I think it needs `package-lock.json` to update no ?

Comment: It seems to be an issue between NPM & Virtualbox.

Possible solution: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/922#issuecomment-419229251

I used solution 1 and solved it a similar problem i had

Answer (score 0):

Building on [memonic's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962245/memonic) comment, there seems to be an issue between NPM & Virtualbox, which prevents it from working properly on Homestead. People seem to focus on Windows set ups, but I had faced the same problem on MacOS.

The method that should always work is to run NPM commands from your host OS. If you want to read other suggestions: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/922#issuecomment-419229251

On MacOS, it is straightforward to use brew to install Node/NPM on the Host and then, still on the Host machine, go to the location of interest and execute the necessary NPM commands.

Comment: yes, running `npm` from host OS works but that's just a stupid solution ... there's a good reason we're using virtual machines in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem after cloning the react application. the problem was extra dependency which is `"fsevents": "file:../../node_modules/fsevents",`. after remove it from package.json file everything goes right.